# How to load parquet files into Power BI desktop (ParquetSharp) error

Tags: .net, powerbi, powerquery, parquet

I want to load parquet files from a folder into Power BI, but the GUI asks for a URL.

I then used the error to load the underlying M code.

I have tried

```
Parquet.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\username\OneDrive\DataWharehouseSMT\Reports\ScrapPages\3A\2023-01-02\date_scrap.parquet"))
```

I get the following error:

> Unexpected error: Could not load file or assembly 'ParquetSharp,
> Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
> one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
> Details:
> Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.ErrorException: Could not load file or assembly 'ParquetSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
> system cannot find the file specified. --->
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'ParquetSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
> system cannot find the file specified. --->
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'ParquetSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
> system cannot find the file specified.    at
> Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.Parquet.ParquetOptions.TryConvertCompressionOption(Value
> value, Object& compression)    at
> Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.OptionRecordDefinition.CreateOptions(String
> dataSourceName, Value options)    at
> Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.Parquet.ParquetModule.Parquet.DocumentFunctionValue.TypedInvoke(BinaryValue
> binary, Value options)    at
> Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.NativeFunctionValue2`3.Invoke(Value
> arg0, Value arg1)    at
> Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.DebugInstruction.Execute(MembersFrame1&
> frame)

This version of ParquetSharp=0.0.0.0 does not exist [earliest version is ParquetSharp 1.4.0.1](https://github.com/G-Research/ParquetSharp/releases?page=6)

If the message only reflects the absence of the ParquetSharp library, then IDK which version I need.

Comment: Are you using the latest Power BI Desktop?  I just tried it and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Yes. I will try installing Power BI again. My instance of Power BI is installed by a service.

Comment: It works for me, too.  Maybe there is something special about your parquet file.  Try this sample file:  https://github.com/kaysush/sample-parquet-files/blob/main/part-00000-a9e77425-5fb4-456f-ba52-f821123bd193-c000.snappy.parquet

Comment: Update, Re-installing power BI fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What is your actual code? Something like this works (NOT a url, a local file)

```
let Source = Parquet.Document(File.Contents("C:\data\data.parquet"))
```

Comment: Parquet.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\username\OneDrive \DataWharehouseSMT\Reports\ScrapPages\3A\2023-01-02\date_scrap.parquet"))